# Given the sequence $3, 4, 11, 16, 42\ldots $ how can I derive a general formula for it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, pattern-recognition

Given a sequence $3, 4, 11, 16, 42\ldots $ how can I derive a general formula for this sequence? Is there any optimised approach?

My approach: the given series is equal to summation of $\binom{n}{k}$ (here $k$ is from $n/2$ to $n$).

Comment: Given any finite sequence of numbers, there are always infinitely many sequences it can fit into. You are perhaps looking for a "natural" or "simple" one. This is not a mathematical question unless one can come up with a definition of natural or simple.

Comment: One idea is to try the online encyclopedia of integer sequences:  https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+4%2C+11%2C+16%2C++42&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

This is what you want:

$$\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^n \binom{n}{k}$$

You can use:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

And the fact that

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate your hint.

Comment: @typedef can you figure it out now?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\binom{2m}{i}+\binom{2m}{m}+\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}=\binom{2m}{m}+2\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}$$
with 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}=(1+1)^{2m}.$$

How about the case for $N=2m-1$?

Comment: @typedef: Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you wont a polynomial,
Let $$P(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$
We can find $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ such that
$$P(1)=3$$
$$P(2)=4$$
$$P(3)=11$$
$$P(4)=16$$
$$P(5)=42$$
Then you have a polynomial which can satisfy your sequence. It is better if you can refer the (Lagrange’s) interpolation polynomials.